# I get the error "Expression expected" when trying to use setState with prevState in React/TypeScript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, error-handling, use-state

I try collect data from Form to allData as a component state , but get an error "Expression expected"

```
TS1109: Expression expected.
    121 |
    122 |       this.setState((prevState) => ({
  > 123 |       allTasks: [prevState.data, ...prevState.allData?],
        |                                                       ^
    124 |       data: {}
    125 |     }));
    126 |
```

I add interfaces.
allData is an array of data.
Any ideas ? How I undestand, its about type of allData, but it seams to right

```
interface FormInputState {
  errors?: FormErrors;
  data?: FormData;
  allData?: Array<FormData>;
}

interface FormData {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  birthday?: string;
  genre?: string;
  getRecommendations?: boolean;
  notifications?: boolean;
  image?: string;
  id?: number;
}
```

Component looks like this

```
export default class Form extends React.Component<FormInputProps, FormInputState> {
  private form: React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>;
  private nameInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  private emailInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  private birthdayInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  private genreInput: React.RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>;
  private getRecommendations: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  private notificationsInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  private imageInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(props: FormInputProps) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.form = React.createRef();
    this.nameInput = React.createRef();
    this.emailInput = React.createRef();
    this.birthdayInput = React.createRef();
    this.genreInput = React.createRef();
    this.getRecommendations = React.createRef();
    this.notificationsInput = React.createRef();
    this.imageInput = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      data: {},
      allData: [],
    };
  }  

  handleSubmit(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.validate().isValid) {
      const formData: FormData = {
        name: this.nameInput.current?.value,
        email: this.emailInput.current?.value,
        birthday: this.birthdayInput.current?.value,
        genre: this.genreInput.current?.value,
        getRecommendations: this.getRecommendations.current?.checked,
        notifications: this.notificationsInput.current?.checked,
        image: this.imageInput.current?.files?.[0]?.name,
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      };

      this.setState({
        data: formData,
      });

      this.setState((prevState) => ({
      allTasks: [prevState.data, ...prevState.allData?],
      data: {}
    }));

      this.form.current?.reset();

      this.setState({
        errors: {},
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        errors: this.validate().errors,
      });
      this.form.current?.reset();
    }
  }
```

Any ideas ? How I undestand, its about type of allData, but it seams to right

Comment: Perhaps you meant `...prevState.allData` instead of `...prevState.allData?`?

Comment: @Spikatrix, this creates an error "Type 'FormData[] | undefined' is not an array type."

Comment: There is no allTasks in your state. I think it should be allData

Comment: @KanatJuzbayev The error seems pretty straightforward. I would recommend reading the typescript documentation and understand what is happening and why you're getting that error.